# Why Google suggesting to use META TAGS in Body?

Tags: html, seo, schema, google-search, microdata

I was searching about microdata for Google's Sitelink Searchbox. So I found a page on google site.

this is the microdata code -

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.example.com/"/>
  <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

URL - > https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sitelinks-searchbox

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) and [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some meta tags are allowed inside `<div>` and `<form>` tags inside the document body.  See [`<meta>`: The metadata element - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) which says:

> #### Permitted parents
>
> - ...
> - `<meta itemprop>`: any element that accepts metadata content or [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content).

From the page about flow content, the elements that allow flow content include both `<div>` and `<form>` which are used in the `<body>`.

So while many meta tags only belong in the `<head>`, when a meta tag has `itemprop` it can go in the `<body>` (or in the `<head>`).

Comment: then the meta tags not gonna violent html5 markup?, as I read somewhere

Comment: and please tell me what to enter in content of meta target tag..     <meta itemprop="target" content="what here ?"/> if we can search on our site by https://example.com/?s=the%20query

Comment: name attribute of input tag is 's'

Comment: Itemprop meta tags are allowed in the body by HTML spec, so putting them there will not violate the spec.

Comment: If the search query parameter is named `s`, that should go where the `q` is in the example from Google.

Comment: what in `search_term_string` and what in place of `search` before `q`

Comment: `search_term_string` in is place of what the user typed.  It looks like you can leave that just like the example.   The `search` before the `q` is the form action that powers your site search.  You haven't shown me what your search form actually looks like, so I don't know what it would actually be in your case.